# Django error: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Учу django, пытаюсь подключить шаблон, но получаю ошибку

```
TypeError at /index/
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app_module'
```

В чем может быть проблема? Подключил вроде все верно, и  в **settings.py** приложение подключено там где надо

```
views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound, HttpResponseBadRequest, request
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'Parcer/index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'Parcer/about.html')
```

---

```
settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
и там дальше дефолтные настройки
]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD2:
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>123</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>1</h1>
<h2>2</h2>
<h3>3</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ```__init__() пропущен 1 обязательны аргумент: 'app_module'```

Comment: Спасибо, но ошибку я тоже смог перевести, а что она значет? Где я мог аргумент пропустить

Comment: И в чем тут ошибка? Реквест в функцию передал, других параметров там появится не могло

Comment: Посомотрите следующую строку за той что вы скопировали как ошибку :) У вас ошибка  ̶в̶ ̶т̶о̶м̶ ̶м̶е̶с̶т̶е̶ ̶г̶д̶е̶ ̶в̶ы̶ ̶п̶е̶р̶е̶д̶а̶е̶т̶е̶ ̶ч̶т̶о̶ ̶т̶о̶ ̶в̶ ̶ш̶а̶б̶л̶о̶н̶ ̶и̶л̶и̶ ̶в самом шаблоне:)

Comment: Вот я и не понимаю где ошибка, путь вроде верный, а ошибку выдает, дополнил вопрос скрином структуры папок из пайчарма, в документации там ничего по этому поводу не написано, и у типа из видео по которому я делал все отлично получилось, а ошибку все равно выбивает

Comment: В самом шаблоне :) я все еще не вижу в вашем вопросе - шаблона.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос содержанием index.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209189/typeerror-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-app-module Не ваш ли случай?)

Comment: Не мой, видел этот вопрос, пишут про то что записал приложение в Middleware, а не в Installed apps, но я же прикрепил код что все верно подключено в settings.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так и не понял в чем проблема, видимо словил какой-то непонятный баг или конфликт, или что-то еще, но я просто создал новый проект с другим названием проекта, другими названиями функций и все заработало как надо

Answer (score -1):

Ты написал что-то странное в инсталед аппс, там должно быть просто название твоего модуля. В твоем случае main, что кстати плохое название.

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main',
    ....
]
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: У меня название приложения - **main**, так что вроде все верно, или я не прав?

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII ну так только main и оставь. 
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main',
    ....
]

Comment: Если так сделать, то все равно не заработает